How to use downloaded tokenizers in Snowflake UDF
How would you create a snowflake UDF using autotokenizer for example:
I downloaded a tokenizer as follows and then uploaded to Snowflake stage:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("tokenizer")

But now I want to create a UDF using the tokenizer in the stage so I can use the UDF as follows:
SELECT my_tokenizer_udf('你好，世界！') AS tokens;

This for example is not working:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_tokenizer_udf(str STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.11
HANDLER = 'tokenize_text'
PACKAGES = ('transformers')

AS
$$
import os
import shutil
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

def tokenize_text(input_string):
    # Define the paths to the tokenizer files in the stage and temporary directory
    stage_path = '/tmp/tokenizer'
    stage_files_path = '@my_db.my_schema.my_stage/tokenizer'

    # Ensure the temporary directory exists
    os.makedirs(stage_path, exist_ok=True)

    # Define the files to copy from the stage
    files = [
        'tokenizer_config.json',
        'special_tokens_map.json',
        'vocab.txt',
        'tokenizer.json'
    ]

    # Copy the files from the stage to the temporary directory
    for file in files:
        shutil.copy(f'{stage_files_path}/{file}', f'{stage_path}/{file}')

    # Load the tokenizer from the temporary directory
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(stage_path)

    # Tokenize the input text
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(input_string)

    return tokens["input_ids"]
$$;

I get the following error when I used the udf, it appears the tokenizer files are now found even though they are all listed in the tokenizer directory:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 24, in tokenize_text
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/646bf8c424d2a161c1dd00001193/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 431, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/646bf8c424d2a161c1dd00001193/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'@"MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_STAGE"/tokenizer/tokenizer_config.json'
 in function MY_TOKENIZER with handler tokenize_text

What's the proper way to import these files and use them?

The process is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/upload-dependencies

You need to specify the files in the IMPORTS clause of your UDF or use Snowflake's built-in SnowflakeFile reader class. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-examples#reading-a-file
